# How to print smallest number from list when mode is not available?

Tags: python, statistics

I Would like to find Mode in python array or list, but if all numbers appears at only once(or we can say there is no Mode) I wanted to print smallest number.

```
n_num = [64630, 11735, 14216, 99233, 14470, 4978, 73429, 38120, 51135, 67060]

from statistics import mode


def mode(n_num):
            n_num.sort()
            m = min(n_num)
            return m
print(str(mode(n_num)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`multimode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode) from the statistics package instead of `mode()`. This will return multiple values when there is more than one mode to choose from. You can take the `min()` from that:

```
from statistics import multimode


n_num = [10, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4]
min(multimode(n_num))
# 1

n_num = [10, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10 ]
min(multimode(n_num))
#9
```

[Note: this requires python 3.8]

Answer (score 0):

try to use the `try` statement

```
import statistics

def special_mode(iterable):
    try:
        result = statistics.mode(iterable)
    except statistics.StatisticsError: # if mode() fail, it do min()
        result = min(iterable)
    return result

mylist = [0, 1, 6, 9, 1, -7]
print(special_mode(mylist))
# return the 1 because of the mode function

mylist = [0, 1, 6, 9, -7]
print(special_mode(mylist))
# return the -7 beacuse it's the smallest
```

hope it was helpful

Comment: That's a nice idea if you're using an older version of python, however it seems like it would be problematic when there is more than one mode that is not the smallest number for example: `[9, 1, 9, 1, -7]`

Comment: I suppose the OP is not clear on this point. I would have expected `1` since it's the smallest mode. The question is ambiguous here.

Answer (score -1):

Python already has a `min` and `max` function built-in to find the smallest and largest values in a list

```
n = [64630, 11735, 14216, 99233, 14470, 4978, 73429, 38120, 51135, 67060]

smallest_number = min(n)
largest_number = max(n)
```